Python Invoke and root for imports when loading modules
We use a Python module named invoke to execute a large set of Python scripts in a nice neat way: invoke loads Python scripts from a tasks sub-directory and allows the Python functions of those tasks to be called in a well-structured fashion.
Inside such a Python script, we have lines like:
from scripts import useful_script_1

...where scripts is a directory that contains generic, "non-task", Python scripts, located beside (i.e. at the same level as) the tasks directory like so:
-- scripts
   -- __init__.py
   -- useful_script_1.py
   -- useful_script_2.py
   -- ...
-- tasks
   -- __init__.py
   -- task_1.py
   -- task_2.py

Some time in the last few years (version 2.0.0 works, version 2.2.0 does not) invoke, unintentionally or intentionally, we don't know, has stopped supporting this approach, the scripts directory is no longer found:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\program files\python39\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "c:\program files\python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\Scripts\inv.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "c:\program files\python39\lib\site-packages\invoke\program.py", line 387, in run
    self.parse_collection()
  File "c:\program files\python39\lib\site-packages\invoke\program.py", line 479, in parse_collection
    self.load_collection()
  File "c:\program files\python39\lib\site-packages\invoke\program.py", line 716, in load_collection
    module, parent = loader.load(coll_name)
  File "c:\program files\python39\lib\site-packages\invoke\loader.py", line 91, in load
    spec.loader.exec_module(module)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 855, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "c:\projects\my_project\tasks\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from scripts import useful_script_1
ImportError: cannot import name 'useful_script_1' from 'scripts' (unknown location)

We could stick with the earlier version of invoke but that will likely catch us out at some point (and certainly catches out those with new installations who don't expect to have to downgrade a component), we would prefer to use the latest version.  We have raised an issue on the Github site of invoke but it might be that the owner/maintainer has moved on as there have been no replies to issues raised in the last four months.  We can't easily move away from invoke as it is woven into our test automation system and we would prefer not to make major changes to the locations of files/directories if it could be avoided since that would adversely affect users of the system.
Is there someone here better versed in Python than us who could suggest a workaround?
EXTRA INFORMATION: we call invoke in one of two ways (and the error occurs both ways).  We call it from anywhere as follows:
inv -r <path-to-parent-directory-of-tasks> function parameters

...or from the parent directory of the tasks directory as follows:
inv function parameters

...where function is one of the functions in a "task" script that invoke knows about and parameters are the parameters appropriate to that function.
If you're interested, the whole shebang can be seen here.

Could you show how and from where you call pyinvoke?

Certainly: original post updated to include this information.
